# How to retrieve data two different edge from the same table in orientDB?

Tags: orientdb

i have an user table with user list and an event able with user event stored

Two table schema
Schema 1: User Table
name
address

Schema 2: Event Table

event_name
event_date

```
Create in edge E with user Table

create edge E  #12:41 to #17:3 ->This edge represent the owner of the event.
```

then  create a new edge with the user table to store the attendee

```
create edge EAttendees #12:39 to #17:3
```

Here i need to get the attendee of the particular event

The following query returns both the edges in E and EAttendees
i need only the EAttendees list ie #12.39. How can i accomplish this

```
select in(EAttendees) from con_user_event where @rid = #17:3

    #12:41
    #12:39


    select in() from con_user_event where @rid = #17:3
    #12:41
    #12:39
```

The id #12:39 is the attendee id and #12:41 is the owner id

How can we get the edge attach to EAttendees only not the whole E

How to get only the values in  EAttendees?

Comment: Maybe you should rewrite your text. It's pretty hard to understand.Did you try **SELECT from (select expand(outE('EAttendees')) from con_user_event) where @rid = #17:3**

Comment: @kwoxer update the text hope this would help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're not quoting the name of the edge class, and due to a quirk in OrientDB's parser, it'll assume that you just meant *all* edges, this should fix it

```
select in("EAttendees") from con_user_event where @rid = #17:3
```